# formatear datos en archivo json con php

Tags: php, json

Mi código genera un archivo json:

```
<?php

$arr_clientes = array('nombre'=> 'Jose', 'edad'=> '20', 'genero'=> 'masculino',
        'email'=> 'correodejose@dominio.com', 'localidad'=> 'Barcelona', 'telefono'=> '91000000');

//Creo el JSON
$json_string = json_encode($arr_clientes);
$file = 'clientes.json';
file_put_contents($file, $json_string);

?>
```

Luego el archivo generado contiene lo siguiente:

```
{"nombre":"Jose","edad":"20","genero":"masculino","email":"correodejose@dominio.com","localidad":"Barcelona","telefono":"91000000"}
```

Como hago para lograr un archivo de la siguiente forma?

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "nombre": "Jose",
      "edad": "20",
      "genero": "masculino",
      "email": "correodejose@dominio.com",
      "localidad": "Barcelona",
      "telefono": "91000000"     
    },
    {
      "nombre": "Pedro",
      "edad": "24",
      "genero": "masculino",
      "email": "correodepedro@dominio.com",
      "localidad": "Madrid",
      "telefono": "92000000"     
    }
  ]
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

espero ayudarte Mariano:

```
$arr_clientes = [
    [
        'nombre' => 'Jose', 'edad' => '20', 'genero' => 'masculino',
        'email' => 'correodejose@dominio.com',
        'localidad' => 'Barcelona', 'telefono' => '91000000'
    ],
    [
        'nombre' => 'Jose', 'edad' => '20', 'genero' => 'masculino',
        'email' => 'correodejose@dominio.com',
        'localidad' => 'Barcelona', 'telefono' => '91000000'
    ],
    [
        'nombre' => 'Jose', 'edad' => '20', 'genero' => 'masculino',
        'email' => 'correodejose@dominio.com',
        'localidad' => 'Barcelona', 'telefono' => '91000000'
    ]
];

$plantillaJson = [
    'items' => $arr_clientes
];

//Creo el JSON
$json_string = json_encode($plantillaJson);
$file = 'clientes.json';
file_put_contents($file, $json_string);
```

Hice una variable nueva llamada `$plantillaJson` e hice un array con el elemento items y al elemento le agrego el array de clientes.

Comment: Solucionado! Muchas gracias @jonasdamher